# Android - How to get current location (latitude and longitude)?

Tags: android, geolocation, latitude-longitude, geocode, google-latitude

I am using the following code to get the current location namely (latitude and longitude), but I am not getting current location (latitude and longitude).

Anyone knows why?

```
package com.ram.currentlocation;

import android.app.Activity;    
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Location_Gps extends Activity
{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      /* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */
      LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

      LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
      mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
    }

    /* Class My Location Listener */
    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
    {

      @Override
      public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
      {

        loc.getLatitude();
        loc.getLongitude();

        String Text = "My current location is: " +
        "Latitud = " + loc.getLatitude() +
        "Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude();

        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

      @Override
      public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
      {
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
      }

      @Override
      public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
      {
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

      @Override
      public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
      {

      }
    }
}
```

P.S.: I am using the following permissions in the `manifest` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CORSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: First mention what permission are you using and where are you checking this in device or emulator...?

Comment: Do you have `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` in the manifest?

Comment: I am using two permission in my manifest <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CORSE_LOCATION"/>      I am getting current location latitude 0.0 and longitude 0.0

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988681/i-want-to-use-gps-but-my-code-uses-wifi-why/5988838#5988838

Comment: [hear][1] is the best solution for this problem.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291728/how-i-can-get-current-geographical-location-of-the-device-programatically/10595644#10595644

Comment: You don't need to request both permissions. If you are granted permission to access the user's fine location, you're automatically granted permission to access the coarse location as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17857993/1318946

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have a mistake in your manifest file. Correct one is:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: I have both but i got null latitude and longitude

Answer (score 5):

You have to send location fix to emulator,as emulator is software you need to provide with location fix.

If you are using eclipse go to

`Window -> Show view -> Other`

Select Android tab and search for emulator control.
After u see emulator control window navigate to location controls.
As u see in below pic

[image: sending loc fix]

After you have sent loc fix you can use

```
Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Where `lm` is `LocationManager` object so 90% of work is done ;)

Cheers!

Comment: OFC you need MOCKLOCATION,FINELOCATION,COURCELOCATION permissions in manifest

Answer (score 3):

In your android manifest did you set the permissions?

```
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
```

As far as only getting (0,0) co-ords you're probably using the emulator. If you're using eclipse go to the emulator control and at the bottom you can send the fake co-ords to the device

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the correct permission. The correct one is:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />`

By the way, your demand can only be fulfilled by:

`<using-permission android:name="ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

So there is no need for `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`