# Loading nearest shops from current location in Android Map

Tags: android, json, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I'm need some help with load nearest shops. Currently I implemented to load all the shops from json which contains lat & long. But now I wanted to load all shops within 5km from current location. Some people suggest me to use distanceTo() for that, but I couldn't implement it. Please someone help with this issue?

Following code loads all the shops from the json (Works fine):

```
for(final Shop shop : this.response.shops){
            for(int i = 0; i < shop.getShopLat().size(); i++){
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(shop.getShopLat().get(i)), Double.parseDouble(shop.getShopLng().get(i)))).title(shop.getName()));
                map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return null;
                    }

                });

            }
        }
```

Edited:

```
LocationManager service = (LocationManager)     getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = service.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location userLocation = service.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

Answer (score 1):

U can use google api to achieve this

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(
            "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
    sb.append("location=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
    sb.append("&radius=5000");
    sb.append("&types=" + placeType);
    sb.append("&sensor=true");
    sb.append("&key=Your Api Key");
```

[here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/) is a nice link , you can follow this

Comment: That's nice, but I think he's reffering a group of shops he has in a DB.

Comment: @ El_Mochiq: you are right. Waiting for you answer. Thanks in advanced

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095919/android-how-to-get-current-location-latitude-and-longitude)

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to get the users location, there are many ways to achieve that, and it isn't as simple as it looks if you want to get the best and most accurate location, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a) thread, really helpful, after that I think you should use something like this:

```
float[] results = new float[3];
Location.distanceBetween(userLocation.getLatitude(), userLocation.getLongitude(), Double.parseDouble(shop.getShopLat().get(i), Double.parseDouble(shop.getShopLng().get(i)), results);
//results[0] = distance in meters
```

So just put an if inside the for statement.

```
for(final Shop shop : this.response.shops){
   for(int i = 0; i < shop.getShopLat().size(); i++){
    float[] results = new float[3];
        Location.distanceBetween(userLocation.getLatitude(), userLocation.getLongitude(), Double.parseDouble(shop.getShopLat().get(i), Double.parseDouble(shop.getShopLng().get(i)), results);
        if(results[0]<=5000)
        {   
                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(shop.getShopLat().get(i)), Double.parseDouble(shop.getShopLng().get(i)))).title(shop.getName()));
                    map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter()     
               {    
                    @Override
                    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return null;
                    }

                });

            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how do I define **userLocation**

Comment: I thought that you implemented how to get the current location. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Nope this is where I confused getting lat & long from current location and implementing the distance.

Comment: Isn't showing anything, shows all or what? Are you running in a device on debug mode? The user location exists?

Comment: Showing current location only. Markers not loading. running on device in normal and debug modes. No errors found

Comment: Can you check what results[0] is for each point?
Log.d("results of distanceBetween", results[0])

Comment: I couldn't use float in Log. SO used system.out: 01-14 18:18:12.690: I/System.out(31019): Not a DRM File, opening notmally
01-14 18:18:12.690: I/System.out(31019): buffer returned

Comment: Sorry, this should work Log.d("results of distanceBetween", "Distance: " + results[0])

Comment: Thanks. But I couldn't see any log output

Comment: In try-catch method getting following error: **Google Play Services missing !** But still current location showing fine

Comment: The problem is finding lat & long for current location. How do I fix it

Comment: try passing true like this: String provider = service.getBestProvider(criteria, true);