# how to enable network and gps location from within my app?

Tags: java, android, gps, geolocation, android-location

I'm trying to get the location of the user:

// getting GPS status

```
isGPSEnabled = locationManage.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
            Log.e(MyLogger.TAG, "Non providers are enabled");
```

I need the user to set `enable network location` or `turn on GPS`.

How can i help the user do each of these options?

> 1. open the device settings page and return to my activity on back press.
> 2. change these two device settings from within my application only?

meaning opening a confirmation dialog that will enable these two settings.

Comment: try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095919/android-how-to-get-current-location-latitude-and-longitude ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well changing these settings in code is not possible anymore after 4.1 (they may be a workarounds to turn it on because on a bug [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528984/android-device-gps-on-off-programatically) but it won't work on 4.3 or 4.4 or you need rooted phones, what you can do is show a dialog to the user to go to settings to enable the GPS

```
public static void LocationAlertDialog(final Context context) {

    AlertDialog.Builder d = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    d.setTitle("No Providers");
    d.setMessage("Unfortunately, you don't have any providers to get your location, would you like to turn on your GPS?");

    d.setNegativeButton(context.getResources().getString(R.string.dialogCancel), new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

    d.setPositiveButton(context.getResources().getString(R.string.dialogAccept), new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            context.startActivityForResult(i, 0);
        }
    });

    d.show();
}
```

call the previous function in

```
if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
        LocationAlertDialog(this);
        Log.e(MyLogger.TAG, "Non providers are enabled");
```

then in your `onActivityResult` you can check code 0 if the GPS has been turned on or not

Answer (score 0):

startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 0);

Comment: can i change these two device settings from within my application only?

Comment: it will change for al your applications installed, you can't change the location configuration for only one application

Comment: no, i meant how can i change the global settings for all application installed but from within my application - silently - without taking the user to the settings page

Comment: with the code I wrote, it takes you to the location settings page, and returns to your app once is changed, then the locations setting is changed for all applications.

if you want to create your own locations configuration view (without using the defaults android) I don't think that you can achieve that, maybe asking for superuser permissions there is a way, but I don't know that

Comment: long time ago was this method for the gps, but it was a bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7890

Answer (score 0):

With the latest location api you can prompt user to change location setting dynamically through setting dialog inside the application.

https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings.html