# Get current location during app launch

Tags: android, geolocation, location, locationmanager

Good Day!
I am working on an android app which monitors user location. I am using LocationManager to get users location, using the following method

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location theLocation) {}
```

Through the above method, whenever there was a user movement, I am receiving location coordinates.

But, now I am planning to get user's location immediately after their app login. Is there any way through LocationManager through which I can manually get the location coordinates after my app launch?

Comment: The current location is not necessarily known when your app launches. So `getLastKnownLocation` can be `null` or very outdated regardless of the location provider.

Comment: see the older [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5988838/1250370)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use this technique :

```
LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

boolean network_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

Location location;

if(network_enabled){

   location = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

if(location!=null){
   longitude = location.getLongitude();
   latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }                
}
```

In this case you even no need to on GPS only your mobile network will do.

Don't forget to give the following permission in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: getLastKnownLocation() may return null, in which case this code will crash

Comment: its working fine for me just concentrate I am not using GPS provider i m using network provider. have you tested it??

Comment: You can not prove a negative assertion such as 'never'. It may return null and you should code defensively by checking location being null before calling .getLongitude()

Comment: @NickT ya I am agree with you actually i have tested it only with network thanks for your comment.

Comment: @NickT i have edited my answer now if you want remove the negative mark thanks.

Comment: I undid the down vote but I didn't mean to give it a +1. The fact is that the answer to 'I want the location NOW' is 'Well, tough, you can't always have it, you have to wait until onLocationChanged() is fired' It's event driven and if there's no GPS or network signal when you turn the phone on an run the app, you are out of luck. Anyway you added the null check, so that's good

Comment: @NickT as i think if you are taking location using mobile SIM network it will not wait for onLocationChanged to be fired ..it only happens in case of taking location using WIFi or GPS .

Comment: Thanks works correctly, you save my day, night and more :D

Answer (score 3):

Try This Code.Hope It will work

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

private LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
        onLocationChanged(location);
      } else {
        System.out.println("Location not avilable");
      }

}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, (LocationListener) this);
  }

  /* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates((LocationListener) this);
  }
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    double lat = (double) (location.getLatitude());
    double lng = (double) (location.getLongitude());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), lat+"----"+lng,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.i("Latitude------------", "Lattitude:" +lat);
    Log.i("Longitude-------------", "Longitude:" +lng);
  }

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
    }
```

Must add required permission

Answer (score 0):

```
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        /*
        tvLatitud.setText("No se tienen permisos");
        ...
         */

        return;
    }else
    {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude =  location.getLongitude();
    }
```