# Easiest way to implement getLocation for android app

Tags: android, python, gps, location

My group is building an app that ties a message to a location. So basically, the app is supposed to get the current coordinates, then save the coordinate with a message to a mongodatabase. Anyone who uses the app at the same location can see all the messages stored in the location.

I've worked with python to make HTML wesbsites before.

Problem is, this is my first time working with android.  Right now, I have no idea how to transfer the coordinates from android to an app.py

Would it be easier to use the android's GPS and LocationManager? Someone in my group said something about using google maps api instead, and json? How's that work? Thanks.

Comment: from where you want to initiate the request to get location from your android application or from server(push to device) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting location from Android device go through this :

[Get current location during app launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286152/get-current-location-during-app-launch/12286444#12286444)

**Process Initiated from device :**
now you have coordinates now in you application so what you can do on launching of a web make an AsyncTask to hit the webservice passing these longitude and latitude and get the corresponding message as response.

**Process Initiated from server:**
for that you need to implement a GCM push functionality in your application what server needs to do it will push a message to device and after getting the push do the same thing as mentioned in process initiated from device.