# How to get coordinate by GPS in android?

Tags: android, gps

I need to get coordinate by GPS and found some tutorial [here](http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/04/29/android-development-using-gps-to-get-current-location-2/) and [here](http://www.hrupin.com/2011/04/android-gps-using-how-to-get-current-location-example) but none of can help me. I just want to get longitude and latitude and show them in a TextView not by online map.
any idea can help me. thanks for your attention.

Comment: what have you done with above links. Implement these and you will get gps coordinates and make ensure you enabled gps and have internet connection.

Comment: GPS will provide you coordinates  only if there is some changes in location co-ordinates if you want the current locaion co-ordinates go for NETWORK_PROVIDER. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286152/get-current-location-during-app-launch/12286444#12286444

Comment: thanks for your time. I'm using android 4 and I MUST enable GPS Satellites in my device setting. Noe everything works great. but thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the androidmanifest also; try [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html) tutorial.