# Get longitude and latitude without letting user open GPS

Tags: android, android-location, android-gps

When I open my home page I want to get longitude and latitude of the device currently situated in, so I can display current whether in homepage. Using GPS it works well but I want to get long. and lati. as soon as I land on homepage without having a user turn on the GPS is there a wayout for that??? as just for whether user has to open gps and then access it and my app is not whether based app.

Comment: Unless their GPS is on, this is not possible. AFAIK, apps cannot turn GPS on or off.

Comment: you can use https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html fairly easy but you can't always trust on it. Or use network location instead of GPS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current location during app launch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286152/get-current-location-during-app-launch)

Comment: it talks about when gps open,,, i dont want user to open gps,, wherever user is I shoulf be able to get its location without opening gps that is my requirement.

Comment: You want receive location updates for GPS and without enabling it ?

Comment: yes I want to grab long and lat without opening the gps..

Comment: GPS must be enabled manually or programmatically, otherwise you cant receive location updates for GPS.

Comment: how to turn gps on programmatically and not let user turn on?

Answer (score 0):

Location data is required for LatLng to work properly. I would suggest prompting the user to turn their location data on when they open the app if it's off.